# GlotPress - WordPress integration

Tags: translation

http://translate.wordpress.org/projects using same header & footer with wordpress.org main site and their login system works together too.. How can i do that?

(P.S: Any other GlotPress & WordPress integrations tips are welcome too :) )

Comment: I don't really get your question. What is it that you try to achieve? Have the same header on two sites? Share one login between two sites?

Comment: Glotpress and WordPress are 2 different software. I want them work together as much as possible like share same login and same looking etc

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is rather easy... check out the [wp_login_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) function. You could use it in a page template for example.